# I'm getting this error: Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to run a Ruby on Rails app on Cloud 9 with the following command:

```
rails s -p $PORT -b $IP
```

and I'm getting an error that tells me I don't have sqlite3 in the gem file when I do. This only happened after I pushed my code to Heroku and now it doesn't run in the console any more.

I already tried 'bundle install' and 'bundle update', I also tried to manually install sqlite3 by running 'gem install sqlite3', none of these solved my problem. I also started going through all the steps all over again to see if that issue pops up again, and it does.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.4.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.10'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
# Use Haml as the templating library
gem 'haml'
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

gem 'themoviedb'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'guard-rspec'

  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '~> 0.21' # for Heroku deployment
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Comment: Hi Cristina. To mark this question as solved, please click the tick/check mark on my community wiki answer below, which starts "(Posted on behalf of the question author)". Alternatively, if you want the ability to earn potential votes on it, paste it into a new answer of your own, and let me know so I can delete the CW version. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

I fixed it eventually, what happened was the version in Gemfile.lock was 'sqlite3 (1.4.0)' but the version I needed was 'sqlite3 (1.3.13)'. I changed the version and ran 'rake db:migrate' and 'rake db:seed' again and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Your app is probably running the production environment on Heroku, but your Gemfile only includes sqlite3 in the development & test groups.  Move sqlite3 out of the groups so that it is available in all environments and redeploy.

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong with sqlite3 versions > 1.4.0 with Rails 5. Mention sqlite3 version explicitly in Gemfile with v1.3.11 or v1.3.13.
(gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.11')